How do I solve error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'" in my flutter app?
I have been building my app and all as been well until today. When I run my project it is giving me the errors below. What could be the reason and how do I fix this:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
/home/ezra0m/StudioProjects/qbus/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19: error: package me.carda.awesome_notifications does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new me.carda.awesome_notifications.AwesomeNotificationsPlugin());
^
/home/ezra0m/StudioProjects/qbus/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:24: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin());
^
/home/ezra0m/StudioProjects/qbus/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:29: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin());
^
/home/ezra0m/StudioProjects/qbus/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:34: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
^
/home/ezra0m/StudioProjects/qbus/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:39: error: package com.baseflow.geolocator does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.baseflow.geolocator.GeolocatorPlugin());
^
/home/ezra0m/StudioProjects/qbus/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:44: error: package dev.steenbakker.mobile_scanner does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new dev.steenbakker.mobile_scanner.MobileScannerPlugin());
^
/home/ezra0m/StudioProjects/qbus/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:49: error: package com.tekartik.sqflite does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
^
7 errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

It means some plugin/packages are missing in your flutter app. Check for the packages listed in error j  your pubspec.yml file. Update all packges version to avoid verion collision in any package by running flutter pub upgrade and before that run flutter clean to clear previous packages and dependencies. Now try to build again. If still facing this prblm. Then attach your pubspec.yml file
